# Choosing the appropriate ANOVA, implemented in R

Tags: r, anova

I have 16 patients and 16 matched controls. In all patients I am measuring a dependent variable `D` and covariate `C1` at a single time point.

Patients and controls are labeled using a variable `Label` (either "P" or "C" for patient and control, respectively) and they are associated with their match with the variable called `ID`. That is, `ID` goes from 1 to 16. So Patient 1 and his/her match are both labeled with the `ID` 1.

Should I use a repeated measures ANOVA or not? Although it is only one time point, the groups are matched.

```
#Option 1
fit = aov(D~Label*C1,data=mydata)

#Option 2
fit = aov(D~Label*C1 + Error(ID/(Label*C1)),data=mydata)
```

What is more appropriate in this scenario?

Comment: For clarity, could you present a table representing each single measurement in a new row and each column representing a variable (including subject).

Comment: What do you mean by 'controls' (are they, different, people?)? 'ID' and 'match' what does that mean, how are controls and patients matched, what did you do that you give them the same 'ID'? And finally what do you mean by 'the groups are matched', what 'groups' and what 'matching'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me why you would want to specify an interaction between your covariate (`C1`) and your grouping variable (`Label`). In specifying this term you are essentially allowing the relation between `Label` and `D` to vary as a function of values on `C1`. The inclusion of a covariate, even as a separate predictor and not as a moderator, is a bit strange to me. If this is a matched pairs design, I wonder what you to need to control for statistically still?

In any case as you have a nested data structure, one option would be to use the `lmer()` function in the `lme4` package.

You could then specify a model as follows (I had to make up some data to demonstrate):

```
ID<-rep(1:16, each=2)
Label<-rep(c('P', 'C'), 16)
C1<-rnorm(32)
D<-vector()
for(i in seq(1, 31, by=2)){
  start.val<-rnorm(1, mean = 50, sd=10)
  paired.val<-rnorm(1, -2, sd=7)
  D[i]<-start.val
  D[i+1]<-start.val+paired.val+rnorm(1, 0, sd=5)
}

DF<-data.frame(ID, Label, C1, D)

library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

fit1<-lmer(D~1+(1|ID), data=DF)
#Calculate ICC 
mod.var<-as.data.frame(VarCorr(fit1))
ICC<-mod.var$vcov[1]/sum(mod.var$vcov)
ICC

fit<-lmer(D~1+Label+C1+(1|ID), data=DF)
summary(fit)
```

Note that I can only specify a random effect for the intercept as a function of the nesting structure of your data. Additional random effects would require more observations per unit of nesting.

The output for the ICC calculation is:

```
> ICC
[1] 0.6626484
```

And the results from the complete model are:

```
> summary(fit)
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
t-tests use  Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom ['lmerMod']
Formula: D ~ 1 + Label + C1 + (1 | ID)
   Data: DF

REML criterion at convergence: 220.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.40382 -0.45215 -0.02742  0.37451  1.74056 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 81.06    9.004   
 Residual             35.79    5.983   
Number of obs: 32, groups:  ID, 16

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  45.0609     2.7124 19.9160  16.613 3.89e-13 ***
LabelP        3.4599     2.1702 13.8620   1.594    0.133    
C1            0.7466     1.3660 17.2490   0.547    0.592    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
       (Intr) LabelP
LabelP -0.399       
C1     -0.085  0.224
```

The ICC value suggests that approximately 66% of variability in `D` scores can be accounted for by shared characteristics in your matched pairs. The final model reveals a non-significant relation between `P` and `C` cases on the variable `Label` controlling for scores on `C1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a repeated-measure design, because the scores come from two different groups of participants (participants in the patient group and participants in the control group). Even if I am sure you did your best to match your participants as best as you could, they are not the same persons. Choosing to treat the patients in the two groups as the two observation from the same patient reduces the unsistematic or error variance, making the systematic variance easier to detect.

Because you have one covariate I would do an ANCOVA. Using your code in R this is how you do it:

```
    fit = aov(D ~ C1 * Label, data = mydata)
```

Mind the order! You want first the covariate and then your predictor. This approach will give you Type I sums of squares. If you prefer Type II or Type III you will have to use the $car$ package. Then you will fit the model as such:

```
    Anova(fit, type = "II")
    # or
    Anova(fit, type = "III")
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it was clear. I am measuring 'D' for multiple different 'C1'. For instance, if I were to measure arm length as 'D', then I would have a 'D' for the left arm ('C1'=left) and a 'D' for the right arm ('C1'=right) so thus I have repeated measures for each person

Comment: Ah, okay, then Matt's response above is the procedure you should follow